# C#:Can I designate a class' member struct to be the implementer of an inherited interface?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

If I have a struct of type Bag that implements interface IGetProps and I have a class Store that has a member variable of type Bag, can I specify in the implementation of Store that I want the Store class to provide IGetProps via its member of type bag.

Bag can not be changed to a class so that I can inherit from it.
IGetProps has many methods so I don't want to explicitly wrap each method with a method in Store.

eg:

```
interface IGetProps
{
    int GetA();
    int GetB();
}

struct Bag : IGetProps
{
    public int GetA() { return 0;}
    public int GetB() { return 1;}
    ... // Many more methods
}

class Store : IGetProps
{
    private Bag bag;        // <--- Can I designate bag to be the provide of IGetProps for Store?
}
```

Comment: No you can't.
However you can inherit store from bag.

Comment: @dgorti class can not inherit from a struct.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408667/inherit-from-struct

Comment: Why is `Bag` a struct? Since you indicate that it has _Many more methods_, that would seem to indicate that a `class` should be used instead since structs are generally meant to model immutable objects with value type semantics.

Comment: @Chris - Bag is a struct because it is an interop loaded array of millions of Bags,

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is "No" your class cannot inherit from a `struct` [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) .

> There is no inheritance for structs as there is for classes. A struct
>   cannot inherit from another struct or class, and **it cannot be the base
>   of a class**. Structs, however, inherit from the base class Object. A
>   struct can implement interfaces, and it does that exactly as classes
>   do.

however something like this could work, it is still wrapping the methods but done as easily as possible. Other than this there would be no other way.

```
interface IGetProps
{
    int GetA();
    int GetB();
}

struct Bag : IGetProps
{
    public int GetA() { return 0; }
    public int GetB() { return 1; }
}

class Store : IGetProps
{
    private Bag bag;        // <--- Can I designate bag to be the provide of IGetProps for Store?

    public int GetA() => bag.GetA(); // <--- c# 6.0 syntax for wrapping a method

    public int GetB() => bag.GetB();
}
```

We implement the interface methods, however the interface methods will execute the structs `GetA()` and `GetB()` methods. Of course we need to assign `bag` to something (ie a contrucutor variable or property).

```
class Store : IGetProps
{
    public Store(Bag bag)
    {
        this.bag = bag;
    }

    private Bag bag;        // <--- Can I designate bag to be the provide of IGetProps for Store?

    public int GetA() => bag.GetA();

    public int GetB() => bag.GetB();
}
```