# Inheriting from System.ValueType

Tags: c#

I have read in many articles that all value are types derived from `System.ValueType`. But after some investigation I found that all value types are either `struct` or `enum`.

As we know, a `struct` does not support inheritance. So how are value types derived from `System.ValueType`?

Comment: The CLR doesn't play by the same rules as your code.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Id up-vote that as an answer as well

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408667/inherit-from-struct, in particuklar the answer from supercat.

Comment: System.ValueType is not a value type.  Look at [the declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetype?view=netframework-4.7.2), it is an abstract **class**.  The type system illusion that a value type value can be converted to an object of a class is well-hidden in C#, google "c# boxing conversion" to learn more.  That inheritance is not possible for value types is pretty essential, value types exist to generate fast code.  They are a good match for the way the processor works. Having to consider inheritance would break those benefits.

Answer (score 5):

> So how value types derived from System.Value type.

Smoke and mirrors, basically. It is *notionally* derived from `ValueType` and hence from `object`, which provides access to a few common APIs such as `ToString()` and `Equals`, but it *isn't* actually an object (unless "boxed") - there's just a lot of magic involved. For example, when you call `.ToString()` on a value type, what that means *depends on whether you've overridden it* - it could be a virtual call (if you haven't, which would mean "boxing") *or* a static call (if you have); or a "constrained" call (which defers that decision until JIT) if the compiler doesn't know for sure (generics, external types, etc).

The runtime has the ability to box value-types as needed (although that isn't necessarily efficient), and **in the boxed form** it is entirely true to say that *the box* derives from those things.

But ultimately, what is important here isn't that `struct Foo` derives from `ValueType` - that's just an implementation detail that makes things work. What is important is that *you can't choose any other base-type* - contrast to `class Bar` which usually derives from `object`, but which can derive from other classes.